# Haskell Warp Performance vs Erlang Misultin testing (how to load contents of a file once and serve in response)

Tags: performance, haskell, erlang, webserver

I want to test performance (request per sec) of haskell warp http server. I don't know anything about haskell. I want to do the same as in erlang code below:

1. load "page.txt" only once from disk (ascii file 100kB)
2. serve contents of that file on every request but without reloading it from disk

How to do this in haskell?

Erlang:

```
-module(test).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    {ok, Bin} = file:read_file("page.txt"), 
    misultin:start_link([{port, 3000}, {loop, fun(Req) -> Req:ok(Bin) end}]).
```

I came across this haskell example and i need to modified it to use contents loaded from a file.

Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder (fromByteString)
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)

main = run 3000 $ const $ return $ ResponseBuilder
    status200
    [("Content-Type", "text/plain"), ("Content-Length", "4")]
    $ fromByteString "TEST"
```

Please help! :)

Comment: When you have some benchmark results, please publish them somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the contents of the file as a strict `ByteString` using `hGetContents` from `Data.ByteString`, then pass it to Blaze's `fromByteString`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder (fromByteString)
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import System.IO (withBinaryFile, IOMode (..))
import Data.ByteString (hGetContents)

main = do
    contents <- withBinaryFile "full/path/to/page.txt" ReadMode hGetContents
    run 3000 $ const $ return $ ResponseBuilder
        status200
        [("Content-Type", "text/plain"), ("Content-Length", "4")]
        $ fromByteString contents
```

I didn't get it to work with relative paths on Windows, but that might just be my lack of Haskell-fu.

Comment: Btw, the hard-coded `Content-Length` as "4" ist most likely wrong most of the time... :-)

Comment: I noticed that during testing. I was afraid lazy I/O was biting me again.

Comment: Why not simply `contents <- Data.ByteString.readFile "full/path/to/page.txt"` ?

Comment: Because I didn't take a better look at the `bytestring` library ;)